# jQChart: Disable Linear x axis labels

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jqchart

I have a jQchart Linear chart. Its plot correctly and working well. I want to hide/disable X axis labels from the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#jqChart').jqChart({
   axes: [
      {
         location: 'bottom',
         labels: {
            visible : false
         }
       }
   ],
```

*Disclaimer: I am CTO of jqChart.*